# java arraylist loop through date

Tags: java, date, arraylist

From my database I call some objects"articles". I get them with GetObjects. Im my GetObjects I have a date for every article.

I want to get a list of alle the articles with the current date.

```
public ArrayList<ArticleData> GetObjects(){
    ArrayList<ArticleData> date = new ArrayList<>();
    while
    return date
}
```

This is what I got, and I am stuck!

Here I get all my article data from my database

```
public ArrayList<ArticleData> getObjects(){
    if (db.getSession().isSessionValid()){
        data = db.getObjects();
        return data;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't have *nearly* enough information to help you: we don't know what kind of database you're using, or how you connect to it, or what your table looks like, or anything. Do you have *any* working code that successfully retrieves *anything* from your database? If so, then please post it; it will help clarify a great deal.

Comment: Now i have :)   I don´t want to make a stored procedure.  I just want to loop throug my getobjects. And get all where date == current time

Comment: No, you're still missing a pretty large chunk:  *what kind of database is this, and how are you connecting to it through Java?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly version:

```
public ArrayList<ArticleData> getObjects(){
    if (db.getSession().isSessionValid()){
        List<ArticleData> allData = db.getObjects();
        data = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ArticleData articleData : allData) {
            if(articleData.equals(currentDate)){
                data.add(articleData);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why ugly?

1. Return List, not ArrayList
2. Instead of asking DB for all data, ask for required data only
3. Instead of returning null, return empty list
4. Why data is shared field?
5. etc

Comment: It's slightly uglier since you don't add a type to `allData`.  Also, there's no implicit guarantee that `ArticleData` implements `equals()` in an appropriate manner.

Comment: Great man! Thanks for the response. Now i can get on with it :)

Comment: @Makato Thanks for paying attention

Comment: My comment was about an idea how to resolve this...